# Error while starting tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, java-6

I am starting tomcat server using maven run configuration :

```
clean install tomcat:run
```

But when I run this configuration, I got this kind of error.

> Feb 20, 2015 10:05:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   Feb 20, 2015 10:05:46 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
>   SEVERE: The web application [/AutoFIE2Web] registered the JBDC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, th
>   e JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
>   Feb 20, 2015 10:05:46 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
>   SEVERE: The web application [/AutoFIE2Web] registered the JBDC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stoppe
>   d. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
>   Feb 20, 2015 10:05:46 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
>   SEVERE: The web application [/AutoFIE2Web] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1@184d7ee]) and a value of type [co
>   m.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityId] (value [36aa9563-83a3-4d7c-9ed4-a15c1beab8a3-1]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create 
>   a memory leak.

I am using JDK1.6.
And not able to find version of tomcat. I am using tomcat as a plugin in eclipse.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your error occurred earlier than this log message. Your app is already closing for some reason when this message was printed.

Comment: I don't think so.. This was the last error message.

Comment: @unknown These are the shutdown logs. The main reason why your application is shutting down will have been printed earlier than these messages. Attach the complete logs so we can have a better picture

Comment: To get the Tomcat instance that is used by eclipse: window/preferences/server/Runtime Environment